# Inline Display Will Not Position

Tags: html, css

Ive been working on trying to get a simple "login" form to be displayed vertically and position it as well.  It seems that I can do one or the other, never both.  Ive tried different ways of doing this neither worked out, so this is basically what I had last.

HTML

```
<form class = "login">
E-Mail: <input type="text" name="id" maxlength="30" value="" />
Password: <input type="text" name="pw" maxlength="30" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
login {
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:185px;
}

login.input { 
display: inline; 
}
```

Comment: Your CSS is wrong. `login` implies that there is a `<login>` element somewhere in the DOM. You have a form with a class of login. You need to target the class of login like so: `.login { ... }`. For the input, you'd want to style it like `.login input { ... }` or `.login input[type="text"] { ... }`.

Comment: `login` should be `.login`

Comment: also, this `display: inline;` won't make sense, `input` tags are *inline* by default

Comment: what they said, and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLbNZ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your CSS is targeting a `<login>` element in the DOM and a `<login>` element with a class of *input*. I believe what you are trying to do is target the class of *login* and element's inside the form with a class of *login*. Try modifying your CSS like so:

```
.login {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:185px;
}

.login input { 
    display: inline; 
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/8u4A6/)**